# jbuilder install fails: no opam-installer tool

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I am trying to run `jbuilder install` to install opam packages that I just built using `jbuilder build @install` (which generated a bunch of `*.install` files for me). However, I get the following error:

```
$ jbuilder install
Sorry, you need the opam-installer tool to be able to install or uninstall packages.

I couldn't find the opam-installer binary :-(
```

According to the [opam developer documentation](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/manual/dev-manual.html#sec25), the `opam-installer` ships with OPAM. I am using OPAM version 1.2.2.

```
$ opam --version
1.2.2
```

I tried running `find` on my ~/.opam directory, but it didn't find any `opam-installer` binary.

```
$ find ~/.opam/ -name opam-installer
<blank>
```

What is this `opam-installer` tool `jbuilder` needs and where can I find it?

Comment: does `opam config exec jbuilder install` work? if that's the case there might be a problem with your opam env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how OPAM was installed. Since I am using Fedora, I used the following command [from the installation docs](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#Binarydistribution):

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/opam_installer.sh -O - | sh -s /usr/local/bin
```

However, all this does is give you the `opam` binary. Here's what I did to get the accompanying tools (`opam-installer` and `opam-admin`):

1. Download the [1.2.2 release](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/tag/1.2.2) from github (I picked the tarball)
2. Unzip it (`tar xvf <filename>`)
3. Run the following commands

(taken from [github](https://github.com/ocaml/opam))

```
$ ./configure
$ make lib-ext
$ make
$ sudo make install
```